# Referencing other modules in a package

Tags: python, oop, module, package

I have a python package as such:

```
myPackage
-----> __init__.py
 ----> base.py
 ----> Feature.py
```

My class in Feature.py inherit from the one of my base classes in base.py.

```
class FeatureClass(baseclassname):
    pass
```

According to pylint, it states I should reference my modules like this:

```
import agol.base
```

in feature.py, but when I run the code, python raises an exception.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Exception: No module named agol.base

Comment: Is `agol` on `sys.path` \ `PYTHONPATH`?  And is your package `agol` or `myPackage`?

Comment: Did you tried `from myPackage.base import baseclassname`?